# call a legacy method to get the name of the daughter class in php

Tags: php, crud

I am creating the dynamic crud, but I want the casting method (database array to object of current class) to be inherited directly to the children I need to get the name the reference this but to the object that I inherited the method, it works perfect if I put it in the class inherited but if I have 10 thousand inherited classes I have to copy 10 thousand times that (that's what I want to avoid)

```
<?php
namespace Models;
use Interfaces\ICrud;
use db\DBconection;
require('./interfaces/icrud.php');
require('./db/dbconnect.php');

abstract class Model implements ICrud{
    private $connection;
    protected $schema='public.';

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function get($id){
        return (new DBconection())->runQuery("SELECT * from $this->schema".$this->getModelName(get_class($this))." WHERE id=$id");
    }




     public function create($entity){

    }

    public function update($entity){

    }

    public function delete($id){
        return (new DBconection())->runQuery("DELETE from $this->schema".$this->getModelName(get_class($this))." WHERE id=$id");            
    }



    private function getModelName($class){
        return strtolower(str_replace('Model','',(new \ReflectionClass($class))->getShortName()));
    }
}
```

this is the child class

```
<?php
namespace Models;
use Models\Model,
    db\DBconection;
require('model.php');

class UsersModel extends Model {   
    private $id; 
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $active;
    private $create;
    private $update;
    private $id_typeuser;
    private $id_people;
    protected $schema='security.';

    public function __construct(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, try to simplify your request, if you have class `B` inherits from class `A` (`A --> B`) what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to make the **$this reference the class that calls it and not the parent class**

Comment: `$this` always is the object that is used to call the method, no matter if the method is declared in the object's class or in a parent class. Is the question about the [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function?

Comment: on this case i not can use get_class() method, see the code in the method cast().

Comment: There is no method called `cast()` in your code, really don't get what you want.